# Moving files to a directory with spaces in its name

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to create a directory that has in its name the beginning of the names of the files it contains. I need this in order to archive it later. I have run into problems when moving files if the directory name contains spaces. I have the same problem when trying to archive a folder with spaces in the name into `.tar.xz` format.

If I execute the commands manually, everything works.

For example:

```bash
❯ ll
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex        84 sep 29 17:13  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex       164 sep 29 17:06  ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex         0 sep 29 16:57 'FILE 123 EN'
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex 607270464 sep 29 16:48 'FILE 123 EN.iso'
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex       486 sep 29 16:48 'FILE 123 EN.niso'

❯ mv FILE\ 123\ EN.* FILE\ 123\ EN/

❯ ll
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex  22 sep 29 17:16  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex 164 sep 29 17:06  ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex  62 sep 29 17:16 'FILE 123 EN'

❯ tar -cf - 'FILE 123 EN' | xz -vT1 -6 -c - > 'FILE 123 EN.tar.xz' && rm -r 'FILE 123 EN'

❯ ll
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex        36 sep 29 17:21  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex       164 sep 29 17:06  ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex 416776676 sep 29 17:21 'FILE 123 EN.tar.xz'
```

If I use variables in my script, it won't work.

For example:

```bash
❯ ll
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex        62 sep 29 17:24  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex       164 sep 29 17:06  ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex 607270464 sep 29 16:48 'FILE 123 EN.iso'
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex       486 sep 29 16:48 'FILE 123 EN.niso'

❯ VAR1='FILE 123 EN'

❯ mkdir "$VAR1"

❯ ll
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex        84 sep 29 17:25  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex       164 sep 29 17:06  ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 alex alex         0 sep 29 17:25 'FILE 123 EN'
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex 607270464 sep 29 16:48 'FILE 123 EN.iso'
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex       486 sep 29 16:48 'FILE 123 EN.niso'

❯ mv "$VAR1.*" "$VAR1/"
mv: failed to execute stat for 'FILE 123 EN.*': There is no such file or directory

❯ find . -type f -iname "$VAR1.*" -print0 | xargs -IF -0 mv F "$VAR1/"
mv: unable to move './FILE 123 EN.iso' to './FILE 123 EN.isoILE 123 EN/': This is not a directory
mv: unable to move './FILE 123 EN.niso' to './FILE 123 EN.nisoILE 123 EN/': This is not a directory

❯ VAR2=$(echo "$VAR1"|sed 's#\s#\\ #g')
❯ echo $VAR2
FILE\ 123\ EN

❯ mv $VAR2.* "$VAR1/"
mv: failed stat for 'FILE\': No such file or directory
mv: failed to execute stat for '123\': No such file or directory
mv: failed to execute stat for 'EN.*': No such file or directory

❯ mv "$VAR2.*" "$VAR1/"
mv: failed to execute stat for 'FILE\ 123\ EN.*': There is no such file or directory

❯ find . -iname "$VAR1*" -type f -exec mv {} "$VAR1/"
find: missing argument from "-exec"
```

Anyway, I haven't figured out some easy way around it. You could also write file names into a while loop, read them from there and try to perform the above actions or replace spaces with _ characters. I would like to solve the problem without renaming files in the simplest way possible.

Comment: Try this: `mv "$VAR1".* "$VAR1"/`

Comment: And for the xargs solution, `F` is a poor choice of a placeholder: that character appears in the variable: `xargs -I'{}' -0 mv -v '{}' "$VAR1/"`

Comment: The general approach is: (1) Prefix your commands with `echo` to see what arguments `mv` is actually getting. (2) Fix your expansions accordingly. A good rule of thumb is to always use `${variable}` while expanding in double quotes and with surrounding characters. Keep special glob characters unquoted if you want them to “work”. Read the `EXPANSION` section of `man bash`, it is important to understand. An interesting pitfall to try out, based on that: `a='*'; printf "%s\n' "$a" $a;`

Comment: *"The general approach ,,,"* .. agreed. Typo fix: `a='*'; printf "%s\n" "$a" $a;` . Good luck to all.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek the `{var}` braces have no effect or meaning for a simple variable unless you're following the variable name with more text and you need to mark out the variable name. For example `var=pl; echo ${var}iable` → `pliable` but `var=pl; echo $var` is still perfectly acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Quotes tell the shell to treat the enclosed text specially:

1. Single quotes tell the shell to treat the text literally.
2. Double quotes allow the shell to evaluate anything starting with `$`, for example `$var` (variable) or `$(date)` (command), but pretty much everything else<sup>*</sup> is treated as literal text.

If you use `*` the shell will treat that as a *glob* (wildcard), matching zero or more characters in a filename. But if you put it inside quotes then it becomes an ordinary asterisk devoid of special meaning.

If you have a variable `$VAR1='FILE 123 EN'` you need to keep it inside double-quotes to allow the shell to evaluate it, but to stop the shell splitting the resulting value on spaces into three parts `FILE`, `123`, and `EN`. But remembering the comment about `*`, that character cannot be in quotes if you want it to act as a wildcard. So here's a solution:

```
VAR1='FILE 123 EN'
mkdir "$VAR1"

mv "$VAR1".* "$VAR1/"
```

You could also have written `mv "$VAR1."* "$VAR1"/` - the important part is that `$VAR1` is inside double quotes but that the `*` is not. In either case, prefix the `mv` with `echo` to see an approximation to what would happen without an action.

Your `$VAR2` would have failed with any amount of trying because you had inserted literal backslashes into the filename pattern. There are unlikely to be any file names containing literal backslashes so the match would fail.

---

<sup>* Backticks are special too, as are backslashes and exclamation marks. You can mix your quotes if necessary, for example, `echo 'Variable $var has the value'" '$var'"'!'` if `var=world` the result is `Variable $var has the value 'world'!`</sup>